# Error opening SQL database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Database that has previously been working fine in now inaccessible.

Error log states

> FCB::Open failed: Could not open file G:\Dropbox\SQL Server Databases\MYOB_log.LDF for file number 2.  OS error: 32(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 1815).

I ran the following script which completed without errors

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus MYOB;
ALTER DATABASE MYOB SET EMERGENCY
DBCC checkdb(MYOB)
ALTER DATABASE MYOB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DBCC CheckDB (MYOB, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE MYOB SET MULTI_USER
```

When I tried to access the properties of the database I got the same error but this time on the MDF file.

What is really odd is there are 3 databases in the folder, 1 works and the other 2 have this problem. As far as I can see, the files have exactly the same permissions - full control for Administrators and SQLServerMSSQLUser$newserver$SQLEXPRESS. Notwithstanding, I granted all users full permissions with no joy.

I am now stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in a folder called Dropbox!!

Are you really running your database off a database file that is being actively synced with dropbox?

The technical cause is that Dropbox is trying to sync it

The root cause is... why would you be doing this?

Comment: Thanks, I feel like a real dope!